# Scrape This Field

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

My code goes into this website and scrapes a field.

The field I want to get is in the right hand side of the page, (**the** **name of the speaker**)

The code navigates to the site. I obtained the xpath, and placed it in the code. Yet the output prints blank.

How do I get it to print the speakers name?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


driver=webdriver.Chrome()
url='https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/record/193286'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

speaker=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/main/div/div/div/ml-root/ng-component/ml-record/ml-video/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a').text.strip()
print(speaker)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded from external source via JavaScript. You can use this example how to load the data via `requests` module:

```
import json
import requests


url = "https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/record/193286"
api_url = "https://ml-couch.asco.org/records/{id}"
id_ = url.split("/")[-1]

data = requests.get(api_url.format(id=id_)).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data["Role"], data["FullName"])
```

Prints:

```
Speaker Marcia Cruz-Correa, MD, PhD
```

Comment: Thanks, would there be a way to do this without json. Id eventualy have to scrape a lot more of the fields on the right hand side

Comment: can you please grab the "meeting" field on the right hand side (as another example) so I have 2 fields I can reference for future pulls? thanks

Comment: @Age If you uncomment the `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))` line and run the script, there you will see `MeetingName` field and many more.